# Android | SignIn Google Api sometimes does not work

Tags: java, android, google-signin

In my app, I've implemented the GoogleSignInApi, with this code:

in onCreate:

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, null /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

in an AsyncTask

```
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            ConnectionResult result = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                GoogleSignInAccount account = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
                authToken = account.getIdToken();
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            return null;
        }
```

The app crash with "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount.getIdToken()' on a null object reference" (account is null!)
Now I've added if(account!=null) {get error}, but why account could be null, if "result.isSuccess()"?

Answer (score 4):

`result` is only the variable containing the result of *connecting* to the API. This does not involve any authentication yet. Only once you are connected, you can sign in. However, the credentials may be wrong, so you get a `null` result.

Comment: Okay, thanks... But the user tell me that he is authenticated and the app crash `at account.getIdToken()`. With my device or emulator, I've not this problem. I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
    You can use the following code for Google login:

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                    }
            }
        }
```

GoogleSignInAccount will give you all account details.

Comment: I do this first time, to request access to user. Then, I use `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).await()` to get the IdToken and sometimes does not work.

Comment: So at the first time fetch idToken form googleSignInAccount .getIdToken(); and store it somewhere.

Comment: Mh... And the token is always valid?

Comment: It should be, as per the google documentation "ID token is a JSON Web Token signed by Google that can be used to identify a user to a backend."

Comment: There is a problem. Each time I use "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token" to check if the token is valid. Is it a bad practise?

Comment: Once to receive the Id token, you can verify it, but why you need to verify it each time?

Comment: I thought, for security reasons, that I should check the token each time, checking is that token is of that user.